# How to retrieve Data Category Group Visibility on Profiles, Permission Sets and Roles?

Tags: metadata-api, knowledge, roles, lightning-knowledge, data-category

Data category visibility can be set with roles, permission sets, or profiles. I'm not able to retrieve any of these settings.

This is the Knowledge relevant part of my package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Knowledge__kav</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DataCategoryGroup</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Role</name>
    </types>
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

I don't find informations about category group visibility neither in `permissionsets`, `profiles`, `roles` nor `datacategorygroups`.

Answer (score 3):

Data category visibility information is stored in the [profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/#profileCategoryGroupVisibility_title) and permission set. Visibility information can only be retrieved using Profile([Permission set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm)
does not support category visibility information at the metadata level).

> Also, [Salesforce recommends that you manually create data categories](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_datacategorygroup.htm#dcg_usage) and
>   record associations in an organization

Comment: Data category visibility can be set on profiles, permission sets and roles. I wanted to know how to retrieve the last association but maybe is better to update the question for a more general question.